# Parse video at lower frame rate

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, video-processing

I currently am working on a project where I need to parse a video and pass it through several models. The videos come in at 60fps. I do not need to run every frame through the models. I am running into some issue when trying to skip the unneeded frames. I have tried two methods which are both fairly slow.

Method 1 code snippet: 
The issue here is that I am still reading every frame of the video. Only every 4th frames is run through my model.

```
  cap = cv2.VideoCapture(self.video)    
    while cap.isOpened():
                    success, frame = cap.read()

                    if count % 4 !=0:
                        count += 1
                        continue

                    if success:
                        ''Run frame through models''
                    else:
                        break
```

Method 2 code snippet: 
This method is slower. I am trying to avoid reading unnecessary frames in this case.

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video)
count=0

while True:

    if count % 4 != 0:
        cap.set(cv2.CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, count*15)
        count+=1
        success, frame = cap.read()
```

Any advice on how to achieve this in the most efficient way would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Getting and setting frames by changing CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES is not accurate (and slow) due to how video compression works: by using keyframes.

It might help to not use the read() function at all. Instead use grab() and only retrieve() the needed frames. From the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture-read): *The (read) methods/functions combine VideoCapture::grab() and VideoCapture::retrieve() in one call.*

[grab()](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture-grab) gets the frame data, and [retrieve()](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture-retrieve) decodes it (the computationally heavy part). What you might want to do is only grab frames you want to skip but not retrieve them.

Depending on your system and opencv build, you could also have ffmpeg decode video using hardware acceleration.

Answer (score 0):

As I get it you are trying to process every fourth frame. You are using the condition:

```
if count % 4 != 0
```

which is triggered 3 out of 4 frames instead (you are processing frames 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7 etc)! Use the opposite:

```
if count % 4 == 0
```

Also although code snippets the two method does not seem to process the same frames. Although in both cases your counter seems to increase by 1 in each frame you actually point to the 15xframe of that counter in the second case (`cap.set(cv2.CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, count*15)`.

Some comments on your code also (maybe I misunderstood something):

Case 1:

```
while cap.isOpened():
                success, frame = cap.read()
                if count % 4 !=0:
                    count += 1
                    continue
```

here you seem to count only some frames (3 out of 4 as mentioned) since frames which are multiples of 4 are skipped: condition `count % 4 !=0` is not met in that case and your counter is not updated although you read a frame. So, you have an inaccurate counter here. It's not shown how and where do you process you frames to judge that part though.

Case 2:

```
while True:
    if count % 4 != 0:
        cap.set(cv2.CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, count*15)
        count+=1
        success, frame = cap.read()
```

here you read frames only if condition is met so in this code snippet you don't actually read any frame since frame 0 does not trigger the condition! If you update the counter outside the if scope it's not clear here. But if you do you should also read a frame there. Anyway more code should be revealed to tell.

As a general advice you should update the counter everytime you read a frame.

Comment: I edited my code above for method 1. The reason I did 'if count % 4 !=0' is because I am, 'continue for all cases where count % 4 does not equal zero'. This leads to every 4th frame being analyzed. Unless I am mistaken.

Comment: You should put `count += 1` before condition then. Count every frame not only the skipped ones.

Answer (score 0):

Instead putting a threshold on number of frames, which would make opencv process ALL the frames (which you rightly pointed out, slows the video processing), it's better to use `CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC` [link](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html) and offload that processing to `cv2`. By using this option you can configure `cv2` to sample 1 frame every nth Millisecond. So setting `subsample_rate=1000` in `vidcap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC, (frame_count * subsample_rate))` would sample 1 frame every 1 second (as 1000 milliseconds equals 1 second). Hopefully this improves your video processing speed.

```
def extractImagesFromVideo(path_in, subsample_rate, path_out, saveImage, resize=(), debug=False):
    vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture(path_in)
    if not vidcap.isOpened():
        raise IOError

    if debug:
        length = int(vidcap.get(cv2.cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
        width  = int(vidcap.get(cv2.cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
        height = int(vidcap.get(cv2.cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
        fps    = vidcap.get(cv2.cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
        print 'Length: %.2f | Width: %.2f | Height: %.2f | Fps: %.2f' % (length, width, height, fps)

    success, image = vidcap.read() #extract first frame.
    frame_count = 0
    while success:
        vidcap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC, (frame_count*subsample_rate))
        success, image = vidcap.read()
        if saveImage and np.any(image):
            cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(path_out, "%s_%d.png" % (frame_count)), image)
        frame_count = frame_count + 1
    return frame_count
```

Comment: @dsBoulder does this help you in speed of processing? can you post some benchmark numbers here. would be helpful for others.